# Get specific element from array

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array called $query

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
        [con_id] => 6
        [con_firstname] => Joe
        [con_lastname] => Bloggs
        [con_username] => bloggs@mail.com
        [con_password] => password
        [con_job_category_id] => 0
        [con_updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [con_created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

)
```

I want to use a few of the values such as con_firstname, con_lastname etc. How do i access them? Im trying to use it like so:

```
value="<?php $query[con_firstname]; ?>"
```

But i'm getting nothing back...

Any help appreciated cheers

Answer (score 1):

That's an *array* containing an *object*. So you need to access the object using array syntax and then access the value using object syntax. You're also missing your echo statement. (And you need single quotes around array keys if this were actually an array).

```
echo $query[0]->con_firstname;
```